# How do I solve this error: 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IncomeForm'.'?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label, objectdisposedexception

What I'm trying to do is get user input from a form (`IncomeForm`) by using a textbox (`TextBoxIncomePrice`) and after pressing the button (`ButtonConfirmIncome`), the `LabelIncome` label in the form `MainPage` should change to the value input by the user.

Everything works as intented, except for when I try to reopen the `IncomeForm` by clicking the `AddIncomeButton`. I get the error shown in the title. It should be able to reopen and accept a new value no matter how many times you close the `IncomeForm`.

Main Form (MainPage):

```
IncomeForm incomeForm = new IncomeForm();

        private void incomeForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            LabelIncome.Text = incomeForm.TextBoxIncomePrice.Text;            
        }

        private void AddIncomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            incomeForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(incomeForm_FormClosed);
            incomeForm.Show();
        }
```

Add Income Form (IncomeForm):

```
private void ButtonConfirmIncome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {              
            this.Close();        
        }
```

Comment: When you close it you need to re-create it `new`. Maybe you want to just `Hide` it? [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=netcore-3.1): _When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are closed and the form is disposed._

Comment: Hiding does not work for what I'm trying to achieve. I tried multiple ways of re-creating the form after closing it but I haven't been able to solve it. Thanks for replying.

Comment: _I tried multiple ways of re-creating the form_ What else than `incomeForm = new IncomeForm(); incomeForm.Show();` would you need???

Comment: Ok, that's embarassing. I tunnel visioned so hard on doing it completly differently because this didnt work at first, but all it needed was this line of code `incomeForm = new IncomeForm();` in `AddIncomeButton_Click`. I don't even remember what I was doing wrong at first. Thanks for the help